# Rails: Current_user should only see records from his/her own group. How do I do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

How can I structure my Rails 3.x application so that the logged-in user can only see records associated with the group he belongs to?

For example,
(Football theme)

Imagine these models:

A Team model, representing each of 30 pro football teams.

A User model, using devise for authentication.  Each user has a team_id association.

A Player model, representing each player in the NFL:  name:string, team_id:integer.

Each user is a head coach, and should only be able to see his own players in players#index.  Rails knows this because the head coach (a User) has a team_id associated with him, as do the players.

Now, with only two controllers (Team, Player) it seems rather easy to manually retype the index and CRUD methods to only display the current_user's associated records.

```
def index
  @players = Player.where(current_user.team_id = ?, 'player.team_id')
end
```

But imagine you had 6-10 controllers:
Tickets,
Trades,
Employees,
Contracts,
etc.....
(all have a team_id association)

Is there a global way for Rails to only display records associated with the current_user's team?
And...how does Rails prevent users from typing in random id's into a URL to find records unassociated with his team_id.  (Imagine a Redskins coach typing in http://www.thesite.com/players/224/edit) and being able to edit a Cowboys player who's player_id = 224.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If all models will have a team_id attribute, you need to define a before filter in your Application Controller along the following lines:

```
def identify_team
  @team = current_user.team
end
```

In each other controller, you should scope your queries by reference to the team variable e.g.

```
def index
  @players = @team.players.all
end
```

You could in theory scope through the current_user (`current_user.team.players.all`) in your controllers but this wouldn't be considered best practice.

Regards

Robin

Comment: Why is it a poor practice to use current_user in your controllers?

Comment: Not using `current_user` but rather creating long association chains

Answer (score 0):

You can use Associations for this. Each table which ever has the user relationship could have model associations as well in rails.

So through relation current_user.players etc like that you can get.

Answer (score 0):

try having a look at the following [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/), ryan bates does an excellent job of explaining this stuff. Also checkout [teachmetocode](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fteachmetocode.com%2F&ei=55VwTtk5goiFB-eanb8J&usg=AFQjCNEr8EpHKkLSoXyhaFpbVJ2GiiADbA) website. All these links will give you the foundation in associations and how to setup database associations between different models so you can achieve what you want. these links should get you started:

[Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

[Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

[Two Many-to-Many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

[HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

[Embedded Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association)

[ActiveRecord::Relation Walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough)

[Active Record Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3)

[Many to Many Associations in Ruby on Rails – A Teach Me To Code Tutorial](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/many-to-many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails-a-teach-me-to-code-tutorial/)